# PyInstaller & Pymeasure : NotImplementedError

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyvisa

I am currently experiencing difficulties using PyInstaller on a code relying on Pymeasure library. The program is working fine from the prompt, but not when started from the executable generated by PyInstaller.
Here is an simple example of a code working from prompt but not when frozen:

```
import visa
from pymeasure.instruments.keithley import Keithley2000, Keithley2400

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
list_available = rm.list_resources()
print(list_available)

keithley = Keithley2400("GPIB1::23")

keithley.apply_current()                # Sets up to source current
keithley.source_current_range = 10e-3   # Sets the source current range to 10 mA
keithley.compliance_voltage = 10        # Sets the compliance voltage to 10 V
keithley.source_current = 0             # Sets the source current to 0 mA
keithley.enable_source()                # Enables the source output

keithley.measure_voltage()              # Sets up to measure voltage

keithley.ramp_to_current(5e-3)          # Ramps the current to 5 mA
print(keithley.voltage)                 # Prints the voltage in Volts

keithley.shutdown()                     # Ramps the current to 0 mA and disables output
```

Here is the output when I run the executable: [image]

Please note that I have PyVISA 1.9.1 installed.

Why do I get this error and how do I fix that ?

Comment: How did you install PyVISA? If you run `import pyvisa`, then `print(pyvisa.__version__)`, does it print `unknown` perhaps?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I did this. I wrote a small code with print(pyvisa.__version__) and it gives me the correct version (1.9.1)  when I run it from the prompt. However if I create a .exe with PyInstaller the output is unknown as you said.

Comment: See, that’s an *important detail*: you are using PyInstaller, and that means the package metadata *is not included in that installer package*. I’m sorry, it appears I missed that. I’ve updated my answer to address this from a PyInstaller POV.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you include the package metadata for PyVisa in your PyInstaller project. PyInstaller has a [utility hook for that job](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks); create a `hook-pyvista.py` hook file (if you don’t already have one) with:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata("pyvisa")
```

and tell PyInstaller about it with the `--additional-hooks-dir` command-line switch. See the [documentation on how hooks work](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html) for more details.

pymeasurement [relies on the `pyvisa.__version__` attribute](https://github.com/ralph-group/pymeasure/blob/634f13abfbcef1b81278e4ac722c3969e5a81c19/pymeasure/adapters/visa.py#L70-L76) to determine if you have installed the correct version of that project. But `pyvisa.__version__` [defaults to `"unknown"` unless it can locate its metadata files](https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa/blob/16e590f8797bffb2307ce22b74110a13cd1f2bdc/pyvisa/__init__.py#L35-L40), which would provide `pkg_resources` with the required metadata to retrieve the version for it.

You can verify that PyVisa was installed correctly by importing it yourself and testing the `__version__` attribute:

```
import pyvisa
print("PyVisa version", pyvisa.__version__)
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you are connected to the instrument, your code references "GPIB1::23" but your print(list_available) returns "GPIB1::24"?

Comment: How does this solve the PyVisa version problem? The issue is the traceback *after* the printed line.